# setAttribute() function in YII is not working

Tags: yii

I am using PHP Yii Framework with MongoDB(yiimongodbsuite). I have created a Model which extends from EMongoDocument.

```
<?php

 class MyModel extends EMongoDocument
 {
     public $attr1;
     public $attr2;

     // rules, custom validations and other functions....

     public function setAttributes($values, $safeOnly=true)
     {
      if(!is_array($values))
        return;

      if($this->hasEmbeddedDocuments())
      {
        $attributes=array_flip($safeOnly ? $this->getSafeAttributeNames() : $this->attributeNames());

        foreach($this->embeddedDocuments() as $fieldName => $className)
            if(isset($values[$fieldName]) && isset($attributes[$fieldName]))
            {
                $this->$fieldName->setAttributes($values[$fieldName], $safeOnly);
                unset($values[$fieldName]);
            }
       }

    parent::setAttributes($values, $safeOnly);
    }
  }
```

In Controller,

```
$dataModel = new MyModel();
$dataModel->setAttributes($_POST['MyModel']);
if($dataModel->validate()){
    $dataModel->save();
}
```

the above code is not setting the attribute value. 
Please let me know if there is any mistake.

Comment: Do you have the attributes in the safe list? If you debug the code, where it fails to set the ->attributes?

Comment: @Pentium10 the attributes are not only string but in array formats too... and yeah it fails to set the attribute but didnt give any error while calling the save() method. but data was not saved in the Database.

Comment: You need to debug, and see if you have the values in the attributes before calling save.

Comment: @Pentium10 checked, no value in the attributes.

Comment: Then debug it, place there a lot of echo/print_r and see where it fails. This is a problem that can be solved on a forum.

Comment: @Pentium10 Thank u! it worked when i set the value of $safeOnly to True. Actually i am using different scenario for the same form.

Comment: @HarishKump post this as answer, and after 2 days accept it.

Comment: @Pentium10 i am new to Yii Front, was previously using Symfony. so i was confused. So if you please put this as answer and also explain why this happened, would be more useful for people like us. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that the 'safe' validation rules is used on each level.

To understand more read this http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/161/understanding-safe-validation-rules/

Answer (score 0):

Try to determine which valdation errors you have:

```
if(!$model->validate()) {
    die( print_r($model->getErrors()) );
}
```